# Will my merged partitions disappear when I reset my laptop?

Tags: partitioning

So I have this app called **EaseUS Partition Master**, which I used to merge my partitions/disks, so that my (C:) disk has more space, since I use the (C:) disk to save my games, so I don't lag in game. I was planning on doing a reset on my laptop, but I'm afraid that some of the merged partitions might disappear, since it also removes this app, of course. Can anybody give me some information? I have to make sure before doing a reset.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting or reinstalling Windows should not change the partition sizes or layout.

Merging partitions is a change to the layout of data on the disk. It is a one time change that involves the movement and changing of data on the disk and is not something the application does "on the fly" while the system is running. It certainly does not require the program installed to keep the new layout.

Comment: Many people use "reset" interchangeably with "manufacturer's recovery" and with the latter the original partitioning layout is typically recovered.